# Android bitmap tiled by X

Tags: java, android, drawing

I'm trying to build a live wallpaper on Android 2.1 and I cannot figure out how to make a rectangular with x-repeatable bitmap.

```
Bitmap backWaveImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.test);
BitmapDrawable backWave = new BitmapDrawable(backWaveImage);

backWave.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
backWave.setBounds(0, this.horizon, 
             this.width, this.horizon + backWaveImage.getHeight());
backWave.draw(c);
```

where c - is canvas.
This code produces nothing.

If I add `backWave.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);` I get the following: [image]

Image seems to be incorrectly scaled or smth. I've got picture in drawable dir, so it's being upscaled.

If I draw a single image (without `BitmapDrawable`) everything looks fine.
I've played with Gravity, with various TileModes. I've even tried to use `Shader`, but nothing helped.

This issue makes me crazy. Please, help.

**2 WarrenFaith**

There's not much to show. I've got a basic drawFrame() function from CubeLiveWallpaper demo. I believe it works fine.

I've done more tests. This time 5x5 red square with white center.

```
backWave.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
backWave.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
backWave.setTileModeY(TileMode.REPEAT);
```

This code produces the following:
[image]

Square is being upscaled to 8x8 pixels, that's ok, but it's definitely misaligned.

```
backWave.setTileModeX(TileMode.REPEAT);
backWave.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
backWave.setTileModeY(TileMode.CLAMP);
```

gets me something unexpected:

[image]

Comment: can you provide your complete draw method and what you really get? Its hard to understand the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've figured it out.

My picture is 10x10 pixels.
When I use:

```
backWave.setBounds(0, 486, 480, 496);
```

I get the nasty image.
When, I use:

```
backWave.setBounds(0, 480, 480, 490);
```

everything is fine.